# Como modificar el caption de un carousel para que se vea el texto como un pie de imagen

Tags: css, bootstrap-carousel

Estoy queriendo agregar una especie de pie de foto, dependiendo de si la foto contiene descripcion o no.

este seria un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que se me ocurrio fue recurrir al caption y tratar de tocarlo con css para lograr mi objetivo

```
<div id="mi-carousel" class="carousel slide">        

          <!-- Contenedor de los Slide -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">

                @foreach($articulo->imagenes as $index => $imagen)          
                    <div class="item @if($index == 0) active @endif">
                        <img src="{{ asset('img/articulos/'.$imagen->nombre) }}" alt="" class="img-responsive">
                        @if($imagen->descripcion != "")
                            <div class="carousel-caption hidden-xs hidden-sd caption-articulo">
                                <h4>
                                    {{ $imagen->descripcion }}
                                </h4>   
                            </div>
                        @endif
                    </div>                 
                @endforeach
        </div>
        @if($articulo->imagenes->count() > 1)
          <!-- Controloles -->
          <a class="left carousel-control" href="#mi-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
          </a>
          <a class="right carousel-control" href="#mi-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Siguiente hidden-xs hidden-sd</span>
          </a>
        @endif
    </div>
```

En el .css

```
.caption-articulo {
 top: auto;
 bottom: 0;
 background: #B984B3;;
}
```

Con esto logre ponerlo abajo, pero tengo una falencia importante en lo que a css y no se como hacer para lograr algo parecido a la imagen

Comment: No me queda claro cuál es el estado o posición actual del "pie de foto".

Comment: @Shaz - donde está el puntero del ratón

Comment: @aldanux me perdí más. Me refería a cuál es el problema, o sea, si el resultado esperado es el de la imagen (donde está el puntero del ratón), ¿en dónde aparece el "pie de foto" actualmente?

Comment: claro quiero que el resultado sea el "pie de foto" que señala el puntero del raton. No encuentro como hacer que el fondo se haga "transparente" o translucido, ni que ocupe toda la parte inferior, solo me colorea el contorno del texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Ver Demo](http://jsbin.com/buhocipeda/edit?html,css,output)

html:

```
<div id="image-box">
   <img src="http://placehold.it/300.png/09f/fff">

   <!-- Si tiene titulo agregar esto -->
   <p id="caption">Foto titulo</p>
 </div>
```

css

```
#image-box{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}


#caption {
  width: 100%;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5); /* asignar el color y  transparencia */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```